# Edit the mediawiki uploaded file name

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

In Mediawiki, we are uploading video using mediawiki api. Its uploading fine.It will be creating as a page like "File:Test.mp4". Now we want to edit the page title alone (Like "File:Test.mp4" to "File:Sample.mp4, but the video will be same). Kindly suggest any solution for editing.

Comment: You want to change the content inside the `<title>` tag ?

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Its editing the title. Can able to edit via mediawiki api?

Comment: Never used that API , Maybe using PHP regular expressions ? If you are fine with that , can you post the title tag ?

Comment: I dont want to edit the page and change the details and to save . Without editing the page i need to edit the title, i am using all are special pages

Answer (score 2):

To rename a MediaWiki page, you move it. This can be [done with the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMove), if you don't want to move it manually:

```
/api.php?action=move&from=File:Test.mp4&to=File:Sample.mp4&token=xxxx
```

When you move a file page, the corresponding file [will also be renamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aMoving_a_page#Moving_a_file_page). A redirect will be created from the old file page, so that both `[[File:Test.mp4]]` and `[[File:Sample.mp4]]` works throughout the wiki.